# $getJSON not being recognized as an array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to use jQuery's $getJSON to send an array of 'ids'.  Here's what my jQuery looks like:

```
var calendarIds = [];
    $("#jammer :selected").each(function(i, selected){
    calendarIds[i] = $(selected).val();
    });

    $.getJSON("test.php", {
      start: start.getTime() / 1000,
      end: end.getTime() / 1000,
      calendarid: calendarIds
                         },  
            function(a) {
      callback(a);
    });
```

And, when I inspect with Firebug, it shows that multiple values are being passed: e.g.,

```
  http://mydomain.com/test.php?calendarid=3&calendarid=4
```

However, when I try to join this so-called array using:

```
$comma_separated = join(",", $_GET['calendarid']);

echo $comma_separated;
```

I'm getting:

```
  Warning: join() [function.join]: Invalid arguments passed
```

And, if I just echo $_GET['calendarid'], I'm getting, it only echos the last id passed, e.g.:

```
 echo $_GET['calendarid'];   //echos "4"
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL should have been

```
http://mydomain.com/test.php?calendarid[]=3&calendarid[]=4
```

In order for PHP to parse $_GET['calendarid'] as a PHP Array.

Once you set it to the correct URL, you will be able to use join() in PHP correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply: So, using the $.getJSON with jQuery, how can I tell it to send an arary?  I tried doing this:
$.getJSON("test.php", {
          start: start.getTime() / 1000,
          end: end.getTime() / 1000,
          calendarid[]: calendarIds
              },  

However, having the brackets ([]) after calendarid causes a javascript error.  Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 3):

In reply to your comment to Mauris's answers:
use this in your object of parameters you want to send:

```
"calendarid[]": calendarIds //
```

instead of:

```
 calendarid = calendarIds
```

Comment: +1 for the assist.  Thanks.  Didn't realize I needed the quotes.  :-/

Comment: the quotes are required just to put the "[]". normally if you don't put the quotes, it's fine with Javascript. but in this case you need the "[]", and thus the quotes.